# I export to the fbx and load it into the clip studio modeler, the mesh breaks

Tags: export

[image]

The obj extension was loaded correctly. I have to load with the fbx extension. I have to apply mobility.

[image]
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

this is boolean error.
you have to triangulate face or tris to quads.
sometimes tris to quads not affect.
you search and affect it.
so it's ok
[image]